# python TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting while reading and writing files

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` in python 3.4.3 while trying to open a file. I am using the following two modules that I made:

```python
def write(file, text):
    file = open("%s.txt", "w" % (file))
    file.write(text)
    file.close()
```

And

```python
import rnumb
import file

def create():
    name    = input("What is your name? ")
    attack  = rnumb.randn(1,3)
    defense = rnumb.randn(1,3)
    agility = rnumb.randn(1,3)

    file.write("name",name)
    file.write("attack",attack)
    file.write("defense",defense)
    file.write("agility",agility)
```

The error is at `file = open("%s.txt", "w" % (file))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the order wrong:

```
file = open("%s.txt" % file,"w")
```

You might find [str.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) less error prone, also use `with` to open your files as it will automatically close them for you:

```
with open("{}.txt".format(file),"w") as f:
     f.write(text)
```

You next problem is trying to import the file object, if you must have it in a separate module import the `write` function. 
I would simply open the file in create and again use str.format to write:

```
def create():
    with  open("{}.txt".format(file),"w") as f:
        name  = input("What is your name? ")
        attack  = rnumb.randn(1,3)
        defense = rnumb.randn(1,3)
        agility = rnumb.randn(1,3)
        f.write("name {}".format(name))
        f.write("attack {}".format(attack))
        f.write("defense {}".format(defense))
        f.write("agility {}".format(agility))
```

Comment: Thank you, sidnt realize "w" would mess it up

Comment: @Lord_Zane55, no worries, I made a couple of other changes. If you want to use the file multiple times and not recreate it every time you call create then move it outside the function but it is a lot easier open it in the same module. You also need to cast ints to str when writing to a file oruse format. write also only takes a single argument.

Comment: Thanks, I am merging the two modules as you suggested. However I so not underatand the rest of what you mean (Im new to python and havent made anything that advanced yet

Comment: @Lord_Zane55. I mainly meant  `file.write("attack",attack)` won't work for two reasons. One `attack` etc.. are ints and write only takes strings and two, you cannot pass two arguments to write so using format creates on string.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually an issue with the method you provided for writing to a file.

In this line of code:

```
file = open("%s.txt", "w" % (file))
```

You use `% (file)` to format the filename, `%s.txt`, but you provided the "w" - the second argument of the function - before you formatted the first one.

So, it's trying to run `"w" % file`so it tries to fit the file into the "w" instead of the formatting string.

To fix this, you could use:

```
file = open("%s.txt" % (file), "w")
```

Or, Python's `string.format` function:

```
file = open("{}.txt".format(file), "w")
```

The difference here is that the format is occuring on the first argument instead of the second, so the argument can find the `%s` or `{}` and fit itself in.